# Indy DnsResolver Invalid Packet Size Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, dns, indy, delphi-xe2

i am working in delphi XE2

i want to run dnsresolver over tcp as it throws error when ever data is greater than 512 byte i think due to udp size limit.

so what configration is needed for dnsresolver to work over tcp with increased size limit.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

TIdDNSResolver only uses TCP for AXFR and IXFR queries, everything else uses UDP instead.  When using UDP, TIdDNSResolver uses a hard-coded 8192 byte buffer to receive the server's answer, so it can certainly handle more than 512 bytes.  Where exactly are you hitting the 512 byte limit? What does the call stack look like when the error occurs?